# making alias in where clause and use that alias in order by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've this simple query:

```
SELECT up.*
FROM `user_post` up
WHERE
  MATCH(up.`title`, up.`summary`) AGAINST(
      'dancers in holoma' IN BOOLEAN MODE
  ) != 0
  AND MATCH(up.`title`) AGAINST('dancers in holoma' IN BOOLEAN MODE)  != 0
```

Is it possible to alias the `Match..Against`s (both of them) and use it in `Order By` clause. Kind of like this:

```
AND MATCH(up.`title`) AGAINST('dancers in holoma' IN BOOLEAN MODE) place != 0
ORDER BY place DESC
```

Brute force solution would be to write two separate sub-queries in `select clause`, alias them and use them instead. I can do that, but I'm wondering if there's an alternate solution that doesn't involve sub-query.

Comment: The alternative is to just repeat it in the `order by` clause

Comment: You can't create an alias in the `where` clause so either a subquery or repeating your code in the `order by` are your only options here.

Comment: @JNevill which one do you think would be faster in a table of let's say more than 10k records. thanks.

Comment: It really depends. I would try both and check out the execution plans (or just compare run times). `WHERE` generally executes before anything else and `ORDER BY` last so that would lend you to believe that a subquery doing this once might make more sense since they won't execute this at the same time if they aren't precalculated, but if that `WHERE` knocks off enough records, then the `ORDER BY` has less work to do and it *may* be faster without the subquery. OR... there are some optimization steps that the database will take under the hood blowing all those assumptions up.